# Searching, sorting and paginating large datasets on the client

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, datatables

I have been using the DataTables plugin for jQuery (http://www.datatables.net) to search, sort and paginate tabular data on the client. The simplicity of implementation and smooth user experience have been a huge win.

Now I have a requirement to implement the same functionality (search, sort, paginate) over a larger set of data, **max 1000 records**. I was hoping to use the same plug-in for this, but it seems that the performance of DataTables degrades steeply when the number of records in the table increases. On IE8, a table of 500 `tr`s already causes the "A script on this page is running slow" alert.

Because the datasets are **not that huge**, I would very much like to do this on the client if possible.

Is there any way to improve the performance of DataTables plugin by changing the rendered markup, disabling some features, feeding the data as JSON instead of HTML or otherwise configuring it to achieve sensible performance for 1000 client-side records on most modern browsers (IE7+, FF2+, Chrome).

Alternatively, are there any other javascript libraries, preferably jQuery, which could offer similar functionality?

Comment: The google visualization api has data table support though I am not sure about your 1000 record requirement. Should be easy to test.

Comment: Klerk - it seems that the Google visualization API table does not support searching over the table. Otherwise it looks great, and I would definitely look into it for future projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in a recent build of DataTables (v1.7.5+). The author changed the sort implementation to not use eval or $.inArray().

Direct download link:  http://datatables.net/download/build/jquery.dataTables.nightly.js

From the change log:
Performance: Re-written the sorting implementation so it doesn't use either eval() of $.inArray(). inArray was found to have a serious negative effect on IE which counts operations to give the 'script is running slow' error message - the new implemention uses a value / key reverse mapping to make the look up as fast as a single object parameter retreival.

Grab the build with the following info (or later)
Nightly:    1.7.5.dev   Sunday 28th November 2010, 14:42    Download    Download min    Notes

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I had already deployed this site into production with sorting turned off, but it seems the latest version indeed improves the performance. Will consider turning it on after I update the DataTables to latest version.

Answer (score 1):

After some further performance testing, it turns out that **sorting is causing the performance issue**. jQuery DataTables is more than able to paginate and search over tables of up to 3000 records on IE6, and far far more on last-gen browsers.

All you have to do is to initialize DataTables with `"bSort":false` and it'll take it like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

I am more fond of flexigrid:

http://www.flexigrid.info/

The number of records is not a problem, because it is implemented every page. So we are not managing 1000 records at a time.

Comment: It seems that on paper FlexiGrid would support all the features I would look for (the feature list cites Search as one of the new features), but none of it seems to be documented anywhere! What a shame.